Why doesn't my scalac prints any warning for missing "open" keyword
When compiling a willingly faulty Scala code implying a missing open modifier, my compiler doesn't notify any warning or error. This seems to contradict this line in the Scala book :

In Scala 3 extending non-abstract classes in other files is restricted. In order to allow this, the base class needs to be marked as open

Here is my code :
animal.scala
package animal:
    class Animal(name: String, specie: String):
        override def toString: String = s"$name of specie $specie"
        def doNoise: Unit = println("I could be anyone, really.")

cat.scala
import animal.Animal

class Cat(name: String) extends Animal(name, "cat"):
    override def doNoise: Unit = println("Meow.")

@main def run(): Unit =
    val c = Cat("felix")
    println(c)
    c.doNoise

I'm running scalac *.scala to compile all of that which runs just fine even though Cat and Animal are not defined in the same file and Animal is not marked as open. Am I missing something ?
Thanks in advance for your help :)
P.S.
When I type scala in my command line, i'm greeted with Welcome to Scala 3.4.2.

open was never implemented, was it? Or if it was, is mostly documentation right now, since to ensure cross-compilation, the default public semantics can't be changed.

I think the warning is still not raised by default (as of version 3.4). See the discussion, "Ad-hoc extensions".

From Odersky himself:

it should arrive in 3.6, later this year. It is already enabled under -source future.

